# Need and how to insert/modify code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

How do l modify and display the help message in the following format so it is easier for my son to understand it?

Example: Help - Display all possible actions use in this game? Score -
 Display your current score? Inventory - Show all inventory?

How to create a shortcut to all commands?

Modify the game so player can quit by entering 'quit', 'exit' or quit functions in this task, and has to exit the while loop?

Make a menu with for 'New game' , 'Continue' , 'Quit' ?

Python Code:

```
 import random import sys

 #############################################################################################################
 # GAME DATA                                                                                                 #
 #############################################################################################################

 # SOME CONSTANTS
 HERO_INVENTORY_POS = 99

 DirectionsList = ['SE', 'WE',  'WE',  'SWE', 'WE',   'WE',  'SWE',  'WS', #0-7
                    'NS', 'SE',  'WE',  'NW',  'SE',   'W',   'NE',   'NSW', #8-15
                    'NS', 'NS',  'SE',  'WE',  'NW', 'SE',  'WS', 'NS', #16-23
                    'N',  'NS',  'NSE',  'WE',  'WE',   'NSW', 'NS',   'NS', # 24 - 31
                    'S',  'NSE', 'NSW', 'S',   'NS', 'N',   'N',    'NS', #32 - 39
                    'NE', 'NSW',  'NE',  'W',   'NSE',  'WE',  'W',    'NS', #40 - 47
                    'SE', 'NSW', 'E',   'WE',  'NW',   'SE',   'SWE',   'NW', #48 - 55
                    'NE', 'NWE', 'WE',  'WE',  'WE',   'NWE', 'NWE',  'W'] #56 - 63



 # '\' below is a continuation character, it tells Python that the current statement continues to the next line.
 LocationsList = \
 [ 'DARK CORNER',                  'OVERGROWN GARDEN',       'BY LARGE WOODPILE',         'YARD BY RUBBISH',
   'WEEDPATCH',                    'FOREST',                 'THICK FOREST',              'BLASTED TREE',
   'CORNER OF HOUSE',              'ENTRANCE TO KITCHEN',    'KITCHEN & GRIMY COOKER',    'SCULLERY DOOR',
   'ROOM WITH INCHES OF DUST',     'REAR TURRET ROOM',       'CLEARING BY HOUSE',         'PATH',
   'SIDE OF HOUSE',                'BACK OF HALLWAY',        'DARK ALCOVE',               'SHALL DARK ROOM',
   'BOTTOM OF SPIRAL STAIRCASE',   'WIDE PASSAGE',           'SLIPPERY STEPS',            'CLIFFTOP',
   'NEAR CRUMBLING WALL',          'GLOOMY PASSAGE',         'POOL OF LIGHT',             'IMPRESSIVE VAULTED HALLWAY',
   'HALL BY THICK WOODEN DOOR',    'TROPHY ROOM',            'CELLAR WITH BARRED WINDOW', 'CLIFF PATH',
   'CUPBOARD WITH HANGING COAT',   'FRONT HALL',             'SITTING ROOM',              'SECRET ROOM',
   'STEEP MARBLE STAIRS',          'DINING ROOM',            'DEEP CELLAR WITH COFFIN',   'CLIFF PATH',
   'CLOSET',                       'FRONT LOBBY',            'LIBRARY OF EVIL BOOKS',   'STUDY WITH DESK & HOLE IN WALL',
   'WEIRD COBWEBBY ROOM',          'VERY COLD CHAMBER',      'SPOOKY ROOM',               'CLIFF PATH BY MARSH',
   'RUBBLE-STREWN VERANDAH',       'FRONT PORCH',            'FRONT TOWER',               'SLOPING CORRIDOR',
   'UPPER GALLERY',                'MARSH BY WALL',          'MARSH',                     'SOGGY PATH',
   'BY TWISTED RAILING',           'PATH THROUGH IRON GATE', 'BY RAILINGS',               'BENEATH FRONT TOWER',
   'DEBRIS FROM CRUMBLING FACADE', 'LARGE FALLEN BRICKWORK', 'ROTTING STONE ARCH',        'CRUMBLING CLIFFTOP']

 VerbList = ['HELP', 'CARRYING?', 'GO',    'N',       'S',       'W',     'E',   'U',      'D',
             'GET',  'TAKE',      'OPEN',  'EXAMINE', 'READ',    'SAY',
             'DIG',  'SWING',     'CLIMB', 'LIGHT',   'UNLIGHT', 'SPRAY', 'USE', 'UNLOCK', 'DROP', 'SCORE']


 ItemList = ['PAINTING', 'RING',      'MAGIC SPELLS', 'GOBLET', 'SCROLL', 'COINS', 'STATUE',  'CANDLESTICK', 'MATCHES',
             'VACUUM',   'BATTERIES', 'SHOVEL',       'AXE',    'ROPE',   'BOAT',  'AEROSOL', 'CANDLE',      'KEY']

 PositionOfItems = [46, 38, 35, 50, 13, 18, 28, 42, 10, 25, 26, 4, 2, 7, 47, 60, 100, 100]

 VisitedLocations =[0]

 # This variable represents player's current location. Initial location is 0
 currentLocation = 0


 #############################################################################################################
 # HELPER FUNCTIONS                                                                                          #
 #############################################################################################################


 def isMultiwordStatement(value):
     return value.find(" ") != -1

 def isItemAvailableAtLocation(ItemID,location):
     return PositionOfItems[ItemID] == location

 def isItemInInventory(itemName):
     ItemID = GetItemID(itemName)
     return PositionOfItems[ItemID] == HERO_INVENTORY_POS
 def isItemHidden(itemName):
     # 100 is the location for hidden items. 
     ItemID = GetItemID(itemName)
     return PositionOfItems[ItemID] == 100

 def GetItemID(item):
     for ItemID in range(0, len(ItemList), 1):
         if item == ItemList[ItemID]:
             return ItemID
     return -1




 #############################################################################################
 # GAME LOGIC                                                                                #
 #############################################################################################

 def GetVerbFromSentence(sentence):
     if not isMultiwordStatement(sentence):
         return sentence
     locationOfSpace=sentence.find(" ")
     return sentence[:locationOfSpace]

 def GetNounFromSentence(sentence):
     if not isMultiwordStatement(sentence):
         return ""
     locationOfSpace=sentence.find(" ") + 1
     return sentence[locationOfSpace:]

 def isMovementAvailable(directioncharacter):
     """
     isMovementAvailable checks whether it is possible to move in a direction in the current location
     directioncharacter - intended direction to move toward at the currentLocation
     returns True or False - based on whether the directioncharacter can be found in the String from DirectionsList[currentLocation]

     Example: 
     if directioncharacter is 'N' and DirectionsList[currentLocation] is 'NSW', this function returns True
     """

     dirString = DirectionsList[currentLocation]
     result = dirString.find(directioncharacter)
     if result >= 0:
         return True
     else:
         return False


 def GetMovementDirection(statement):
     verb=GetVerbFromSentence(statement)
     noun=GetNounFromSentence(statement)
     if len(verb)==1:
         return verb
     if verb == 'GO':
         return noun[:1]
     return ''

 def GetScore():
     score = 0
     for name in ItemList:
         if isItemInInventory(name):
             score +=1
     return score

 #############################################################################################
 # END GAME LOGIC                                                                            #
 #############################################################################################

 #############################################################################################
 # BEGIN PRESENTATION LOGIC                                                                  #
 #############################################################################################

 def DisplayCongratulation():
     print("""
  __     __                    _       
  \ \   / /                   (_)      
   \ \_/ /__  _   _  __      ___ _ __  
    \   / _ \| | | | \ \ /\ / / | '_ \ 
     | | (_) | |_| |  \ V  V /| | | | |
     |_|\___/ \__,_|   \_/\_/ |_|_| |_|

  """)                                     


 def DisplayInventory():
     strItems=""
     for i in range(len(PositionOfItems)):
         if PositionOfItems[i] == HERO_INVENTORY_POS:
             strItems = strItems + " "+ ItemList[i]

     if len(strItems) == 0:
         strItems = "NOTHING"
     print("YOU ARE CARRYING:" + strItems)


 def DisplayMap():

     """
      Each row of the map is consisted of 3 lines
      The first line - contains exit to North
      The second line - contains exits to West and East plus room no.
      The third line - contains exit to South

     """
     Line1 = ""
     Line2 = ""
     Line3 = ""
     # Use a FOR loop to draw every room
     for Index in range (0, 64, 1):
         if Index in VisitedLocations:
             # assign the exits at location 'Index' to currentValues
             # e.g. "NSW" if there are exits to North, South, and West
             currentValues=DirectionsList[Index]

             # if there is exit to the north draw a gap between the blocks
             if "N" in currentValues:
                 Line1 += "█  █"
             # otherwise, draw a wall
             else:
                 Line1 += "████"

             if "W" in currentValues:
                 Line2 += (" ") + PrintableInts(Index)
             else:
                 Line2 += ("█") + PrintableInts(Index)


             if "E" in currentValues:
                 Line2 += " "
             else:
                 Line2 += "█"

             if "S" in currentValues:
                 Line3 += "█  █"
             else:
                 Line3 += "████"
         else:
             Line1 += "    "
             Line2 += "    "
             Line3 += "    "
         # Draw the first row of rooms if 8 rooms have been processed.     
         if (Index + 1) % 8 == 0:
             print (Line1)
             print (Line2)
             print (Line3)
             # Emptying the lines for the next row of 8 rooms.
             Line1 = ""
             Line2 = ""
             Line3 = "" 

 ###
 def ExamineCoat():
     if currentLocation == 32 and isItemHidden("Key"):
         PositionOfItems[GetItemID("KEY")] = 32
         print ("YOU EXAMINE THE COAT AND FIND A KEY IN THE POCKET")
     elif currentLocation == 32 and not isItemHidden("Key"):
         print ("IT\'S A DIRTY OLD COAT")
     else:
         print ("WHAT COAT?")

 def ExamineDrawer():
     if currentLocation == 43 and isItemInInventory("KEY") :
         print ("YOU UNLOCK THE DRAWER AND FIND IT IS EMPTY")
     elif currentLocation == 43 and not isItemInInventory("KEY") :
         print ("UNFORTUNATELY THE DRAWER IS LOCKED")
     else:
         print ("WHAT DRAWER?")


 def ExamineRubbish():
     if currentLocation == 3:
         print ("THE RUBBISH IS FILTHY")
     else:
         print ("WHAT RUBBISH?")

 def ExamineWall():
     if currentLocation == 43:
         LocationsList[currentLocation] = "STUDY WITH DESK"
         DirectionsList[currentLocation]="NW"
         print ("YOU LOOK AT THE WALL AND DISCOVER IT IS FALSE!\nYOU DISCOVER A NEW EXIT")
     else:
         print ("NO INTERESTING WALLS HERE")
 def ExamineDoor():
     if currentLocation == 28 and  isItemInInventory("KEY"):
         DirectionsList[currentLocation]="SEW"
         print ("YOU UNLOCK THE DOOR AND DISCOVER A NEW LOCATION!")
     elif currentLocation == 28 and  not isItemInInventory("KEY"):
         print ("UNFORTUNATELY THE DOOR IS LOCKED")
     else:
         print ("NO INTERESTING DOOR HERE")

 def ExamineBooks():
     if currentLocation == 42 and isItemHidden("CANDLE"):
         print ("YOU LOOK AT THE BOOKS AND FOUND A CANDLE IN BETWEEN BOOKS!")
         PositionOfItems[GetItemID("CANDLE")] = 42
     elif currentLocattion == 42 and not isItemHidden("CANDLE"):
         print ("THE BOOKS LOOK EVIL")
     else:
         print ("NO BOOKS HERE")
 def DoExamine(noun) :
     if noun == "COAT":
         ExamineCoat()
     elif noun == "DRAWER":
         ExamineDrawer( )
     elif noun == "RUBBISH":
         ExamineRubbish()
     elif noun == "WALL":
         ExamineWall()
     elif noun == "DOOR":
         ExamineDoor()
     elif noun == "BOOKS":
         ExamineBooks()
     else:
         print ("WHAT "+noun+"?")



 def PrintableInts(value):
     if(value<10):
         return " "+str(value)
     return str(value)


 #############################################################################################
 # END PRESENTATION LOGIC                                                                    #
 #############################################################################################


 def ListItemsAtPosition():
     strItems=""
     for i in range(0, len(PositionOfItems), 1):
         if PositionOfItems[i] == currentLocation:
             strItems = strItems + " "+ ItemList[i]
     return strItems

 def ItemsAvailableAtPosition():
     for i in range(0, len(PositionOfItems), 1):
         if PositionOfItems[i] == currentLocation:
             return True
     return False


 def Go(statement, nowLocation):
     directioncharacter = ''

     verb=GetVerbFromSentence(statement)
     noun=GetNounFromSentence(statement)

     directioncharacter = verb
     if verb == 'GO':
         directioncharacter = noun[:1]

     if isMovementAvailable(directioncharacter):
         if directioncharacter == 'N':
             nowLocation -= 8
         elif directioncharacter == 'S':
             nowLocation += 8
         elif directioncharacter == 'W':
             nowLocation -= 1
         elif directioncharacter == 'E':
             nowLocation += 1
     return nowLocation

 def GetItem(noun):
     ItemID = GetItemID(noun)
     if isItemAvailableAtLocation(ItemID,currentLocation):
         PositionOfItems[ItemID]=HERO_INVENTORY_POS
         print("YOU ARE NOW CARRYING A",noun, file=sys.stderr)
     else:
         print("SORRY YOU CANNOT TAKE A ", noun)


 def DropItem(noun):
     ItemID = GetItemID(noun)
     if isItemAvailableAtLocation(ItemID, HERO_INVENTORY_POS):
         PositionOfItems[ItemID] = currentLocation
         print("YOU HAVE DROPPED THE ", noun)
     else:
         print("YOU CANNOT DROP THAT WHICH YOU DO NOT POSSESS")

 ###
 def OpenDoor():
     if currentLocation == 28 and isItemInInventory("KEY"):
         DirectionsList[currentLocation]="SEW"
         print("THE DOOR IS NOW OPEN! REVEALLING A NEW EXIT!")
     else:
         print("THE DOOR IS LOCKED")


 def ProcessStatement(statement):
     global currentLocation
     '''
       A statement can be either a verb or a verb + a noun
       If a statement is consisted of 1 verb and 1 noun, (separated by a space), it can looks like 'examine desk', 'get axe' ..etc
     '''

     verb=GetVerbFromSentence(statement)
     noun=GetNounFromSentence(statement)    

     if verb == "HELP":
         print ("I UNDERSTAND THE FOLLOWING WORDS:")

         print(VerbList)

     elif verb == "SCORE":
         print("YOUR CURRENT SCORE IS:", GetScore())

     elif verb == "INVENTORY" :
         DisplayInventory()

     elif verb == "GET" :
         GetItem(noun)

     elif verb == "OPEN" and noun == "DOOR":
         OpenDoor()

     elif verb == "DROP":
         DropItem(noun)

     elif verb == "EXAMINE":
         DoExamine(noun)

     elif verb == "SHOW" and noun == "MAP":
         DisplayMap()

     elif verb == 'N' or verb == 'S' or verb == 'E' or verb == 'W' or verb == 'U' or verb == 'D' or verb == 'GO':  
         newLocationID = Go(statement,currentLocation)
         if currentLocation != newLocationID:
             print("YOU MOVED FROM " + LocationsList[currentLocation] + " TO " + LocationsList[newLocationID], file=sys.stderr)
         else:
             print("YOU ARE UNABLE TO MOVE IN THAT DIRECTION")
         currentLocation = newLocationID



 # Existing missions:
 # Go to location 32 and 'examine coat' to find a key
 # Go to location 28 and 'open door' with the key in inventory.

 # Go to location 43 and 'examine wall' to find a new exit into a secret room.

 def Game():
     # Win condition: pick up more than 5 items and go back to location 0
     while not (GetScore() >= 5 and currentLocation == 0):

         print("========Haunted House=========")
         print("YOU ARE LOCATED IN A ", LocationsList[currentLocation],"("+str(currentLocation)+")")
         if ItemsAvailableAtPosition():
             print("YOU CAN SEE THE FOLLOWING ITEMS AT THIS LOCATION: ", ListItemsAtPosition())
         print("VISIBLE EXITS: ", DirectionsList[currentLocation])
         DisplayMap()

         statement = input("WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO NEXT?")
         statement = statement.upper()
         ProcessStatement(statement)
         if not (currentLocation in VisitedLocations):
             VisitedLocations.append(currentLocation)


     DisplayCongratulation()

 # Program starts here!
 Game()
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I'll gladly revert it. Good luck with your code! Personally I think it'd be good to work on the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Cool game. I don't know if you wanted to build the whole command line interpreter from scratch as an exercise, but a lot of the heavy lifting of cli-style python scripts can be done through the [Python cmd module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html)

You can define individual commands, maintain internal state, and have cmd autoformat help messages for you.

Alternatively, consider storing verbs and their shortcuts or aliases in a dictionary whose values are functions that evaluate the statement. This can help simplify those if-statements.

```
def do_help(args):
    print('this is the help statement')
...
verb_dictionary = {'HELP':do_help, 'h':do_help, 'N', go_north ... }
```